# Nomenclature of Organic Compound from Condensed Formula

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I am just unable to name $\ce{C6H5CH2C6H5CH2C6H5}$ using IUPAC nomenclature.
I tried searching online however I couldn't find a name for it.

Comment: The formula you have given is incorrect - the middle phenyl group should be C6H4. Furthermore, you didn't give any information about the substitution pattern on the middle ring. The current answer is just one of the possible isomers.

Comment: Related: [What is the correct nomenclature for diphenyl methane?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/34019/7951)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this? 1,4-dibenzylbenzene

http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.205991.html?rid=80e8a67d-0782-4794-bf27-db26ccd1ce39&page_num=0

What I did was go to their Structure tab and input what I thought to be the compound you typed. If this isn't it, you can probably draw what you think it is.

Hope this helped!