# Does the name 4-nitrodiphenylmethane follow the IUPAC rules?

Tags: nomenclature

Does the name **4-nitrodiphenylmethane** follow the IUPAC rules? It doesn't make sense to me. How can you assign a locant of 4 when your stem name is just methane?

[image]

Comment: I feel like the stem is "diphenylmethane" not just methane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *preferred* IUPAC name for the compound that is given in the question is **1-benzyl-4-nitrobenzene;** however, that does not necessarily mean that other names are not in accordance with IUPAC nomenclature.

The name **diphenylmethane** actually is in accordance with current IUPAC recommendations (see Subsection P-44.1.2.2 in *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*), although the preferred name is **1,1'-methylenedibenzene** (see also [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/34036/7951)).

The name diphenylmethane treats the phenyl groups alike as substituents of methane.

If now one of the simple phenyl substituents in diphenylmethane is replaced by a compound 4-nitrophenyl substituent, the analogous name of the resulting compound is **(4-nitrophenyl)(phenyl)methane** and not ‘4-nitrodiphenylmethane’.

Comment: Ooh, thanks! What if the other phenyl group had been substituted with NO2 para to the methylene substituent? Do I name it bis(4-nitrophenyl)methane?